# html email with php not displaying correctly

Tags: php, html, html-email

Tried looking on here but wasn't able to resolve me issue. Trying to use php to send an HTML email, the e-mail sends out but when I get the e-mail all it does is display the actual html code. I tried different header code but it still will not display correctly. Any help would be awesome! I a sure its pretty simple and I am just missing something easy.

```
<?php
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
    $headers = "From: useremail@email.com\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST["email"] . "\n";
    $headers .= "Return-path: " . $_POST["email"];
    $sendTo = "useremail@email.com";
    $subject = "Pex Heat Estimate Request from Customer {$_POST['custname']}-{$_POST['ProjectName']}:";
    $message = "Here is a your Copy of Pex Heat Estimate Request from Customer {$_POST['custname']}-{$_POST['ProjectName']}";
    $message .=  '<html><body><table>';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            $message .= '<tr><td>' . $key . '</td><td>' . $value . '</td></tr>';
        }
        else {
            foreach ($_POST[$key] as $itemvalue) {
                $message .= '<tr><td>' . $key . '</td><td>' . $itemvalue . '</td></tr>';
            }
        }
    }
    $message .= '</body></table></html>';

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Thanks to @fred for the fix! - I was now able to start adding html tags, etc. my last question is how to I add a : after $key - Just trying to format the e-mail a bit better to distinguish between the column with the label and the actual data on the right.

```
<?php
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
    $headers .= "From: jonvanasco@gmail.com\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST["email"] . "\n";
    $headers .= "Return-path: " . $_POST["email"];
    $sendTo = "jonvanasco@gmail.com";
    $subject = "Pex Heat Estimate Request from Customer {$_POST['custname']}-{$_POST['ProjectName']}:";
    $message = "Here is a your Copy of Pex Heat Estimate Request from Customer {$_POST['custname']}-{$_POST['ProjectName']}";
    $message .=  '<html><body><p>Thank you for submitting your Estimate Request with Pexheat.com : <u></u><u></u> Please remember to fax or email a floor plan diagram to us at 631-382-8225 or <a href="mailto:quotes@pexheat.com" target="_blank">quotes@pexheat.com</a>.<u></u><u></u></p>
<p>- Pexheat.com Staff</p><br></br><div>
  <center><p align="center"><h3><strong>Pexheat.com Estimate Request</strong></h3><u></u><u></u></p></center><br></br>
</div><table width="80%" align="center">';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            $message .= '<tr><td>' . $key . '</td><td>' . $value . '</td></tr>';
        }
        else {
            foreach ($_POST[$key] as $itemvalue) {
                $message .= '<tr><td>' . $key . '</td><td>' . $itemvalue . '</td></tr>';
            }
        }
    }
    $message .= '</table></body><div><h5 align="center">Pexheat.com, 30 South Ave, Smithtown, NY 11787, Phone 631-240-9173, Fax 631-382-8225 | email: <a href="mailto:quotes@pexheat.com" target="_blank">quotes@pexheat.com</a>, Website: <a href="http://www.pexheat.com/" target="_blank">www.pexheat.com</a></h5></div></html>';

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Comment: You have a (concatenate) dot missing in `$headers = "From: useremail@email.com\n";` so do `$headers .= "From: useremail@email.com\n";` while deleting the one in `$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";` so `$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";`

Comment: Simple: Don't build your own mime emails. Use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer. They'll reduce that mess to just a few lines of actual mail-related code, and the rest is just you feeding in html.

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- that fixed my issue! I knew it would be something simple that I was missing.

Comment: *"Thanks @fred that fixed my issue - I have another question now. How would I implement the following html code in my above PHP code?"* - As per your edit, that would need to be another question. Your original question [`has been answered`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23837134/) - Do not modify your original question and add something after the fact.

Comment: In response to your new question, yes.  You should be able to add your additional markup between lines 13 and 14.  You should probably post this as a new question though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- How would I add a : after $key? Just trying to format the e-mail better

Comment: Try this `$message .= '<tr><td>' . $key . ' :</td><td>'...` or `$message .= '<tr><td>' . $key . '</td><td> :' . $itemvalue . '</td></tr>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a (concatenate) dot missing in

```
$headers = "From: useremail@email.com\n";
          ^-- there
```

so do

```
$headers .= "From: useremail@email.com\n";
```

while deleting the one in

```
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
         ^-- delete that
```

so

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
```

what is happening is that your headers are broken and that prevents the headers from being properly "chained".

When a (chain) link is broken, it's just "broken" and doesn't "work" anymore.

```
<?php
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
    $headers .= "From: useremail@email.com\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: " . $_POST["email"] . "\n";
    $headers .= "Return-path: " . $_POST["email"];
    $sendTo = "useremail@email.com";
    $subject = "Pex Heat Estimate Request from Customer {$_POST['custname']}-{$_POST['ProjectName']}:";
    $message = "Here is a your Copy of Pex Heat Estimate Request from Customer {$_POST['custname']}-{$_POST['ProjectName']}";
    $message .=  '<html><body><table>';
    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if (!is_array($value)) {
            $message .= '<tr><td>' . $key . '</td><td>' . $value . '</td></tr>';
        }
        else {
            foreach ($_POST[$key] as $itemvalue) {
                $message .= '<tr><td>' . $key . '</td><td>' . $itemvalue . '</td></tr>';
            }
        }
    }
    $message .= '</body></table></html>';

    mail($sendTo, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

---

Plus, as Marc stated in his comment, which I quote:

*"Simple: Don't build your own mime emails. Use PHPMailer or Swiftmailer. They'll reduce that mess to just a few lines of actual mail-related code, and the rest is just you feeding in html."*

Links:

- [**PHPMailer**](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)
- [**Swiftmailer**](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the code here

```
$message .= '</body></table></html>';
```

to

```
$message .= '</table></body></html>';
```

You need to close the table first and then body

Comment: fred's comment is the reason it is not working as html. This is just correcting bad markup but it would still try to render.